performance of getting a new list with an additional value
To get a new list from a list with an additional value, I used to think that list_b = [*list_a, value] is more performant than list_b = list_a + [value], as the latter generates an intermediate [value].
However, according to the benchmark (tested in Python 3.12.3 / Windows 10), it seems that the result is opposite:

from timeit import timeit
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_data_points = 1000
step = 10
methods = [
    # ordered from slowest to fastest to make the key easier to read
    # "list_b = list_a.copy(); list_b += (value,)",
    # "list_b = list_a.copy(); list_b.append(value)",
    # "list_b = list(list_a); list_b.append(value)",
    "list_b = [*list_a, value]",
    "list_b = list_a + [value]",
]

x = list(range(0, num_data_points * step, step))
y = [[] for _ in methods]
for i in x:
    list_a = list(range(i))
    random.shuffle(list_a)
    value = random.randint(0, num_data_points * step)
    setup = f"list_a = {list_a}; value = {value}"
    for method_index, method in enumerate(methods):
        y[method_index].append(timeit(method, setup=setup, number=800))
    print(i, "out of", num_data_points * step)

ax = plt.axes()
for method_index, method in enumerate(methods):
    ax.plot(x, y[method_index], label=method)
ax.set(xlabel="size of the list", ylabel="time (s) (lower is better)")
ax.legend()
ax.figure.canvas.get_default_filetype = lambda: 'svg'
plt.show()

I have also checked the disassembled code:
import dis

list_a = [1, 2, 3]
value = 4

def method_1():
    list_b = [*list_a, value]

def method_2():
    list_b = list_a + [value]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dis.dis(method_1)
    dis.dis(method_2)

and have got the following:
# list_b = [*list_a, value]
  6           0 RESUME                   0

  7           2 BUILD_LIST               0
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list_a)
             14 LIST_EXTEND              1
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (value)
             26 LIST_APPEND              1
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (list_b)
             30 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)

# list_b = list_a + [value]
  9           0 RESUME                   0

 10           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list_a)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (value)
             22 BUILD_LIST               1
             24 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             28 STORE_FAST               0 (list_b)
             30 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)

which doesn't seem sufficient to explain the performance difference without knowning further implementation details.
Can someone help explain why?

Have you tried disassembling them?

How much time does that intermediate [value] take?

On such short lists with such a small number of repeated timings the time difference seems hardly significant (less than 0.1 ns per call on lists of size 10K). But if you look at the disassembly then you'll see that v + [a] is a tiny bit more efficient than [*v, a].

@mudskipper can you elaborate why v + [a] is a tiny bit more efficient than [*v, a] according to the disassembly?

@mudskipper Thank you for the explanation. I have checked the disassembly, and I don't think we can simply say that v + lis is something like v.extend(lis) since they clearly don't do the same thing—the latter extends v in place while the former makes a new list, which must include a list creation (and items insertion) somewhere internally.

You're right - they don't do the same thing. My point however was to try to make the disassembly a bit more intuitive by "translating back" into Python - this was only intended to try to hightlight the difference between the two calls, so I did not want to suggest this was exactly "doing the same thing".

Why do you shuffle? I suspect it somewhat hides the actual difference and you'd get a clearer picture without it. I might even use list_a = [i % 4 for i in range(i)] (and no shuffling).

On my PC, [*list_a, value] is faster. Also, the line is more straight (i.e. more stable) than yours. By the way, timeit returns the total runtime, not the runtime of a single run. So, 0.01 means 10 milliseconds total, 12.5 microseconds per run. 800 times may be a little too few to compare such short runtimes. Why not try 10000?

I overlooked that you were using Python 3.12, so I re-ran with 3.12.0 and this time was able to reproduce the same result. I ran the test repeatedly with both 3.11 and 3.12, and it does not reproduce with 3.11, but it does with 3.12. Somehow this seems to be a Python 3.12 (or later) specific issue.

The difference is very minimal as far as I can see. I think this is Happening due to the use of *. From another use case I recall, it adds a small overhead as it iterates over a list.
